# Z-index not working with div's Fixed Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have two divs, one is a modal view and one is a [popupmenu](https://github.com/filfat-Studios-AB/cordova-plugin-context-menu), I want the popup to be above the modal, so the popup has

```
z-index:9999999999;
position:fixed;
```

And the modal has

```
z-index:10;
position:fixed;
```

But when I click on the page, I see behavior as though I clicked the modal not the popup why is this happening? Both div's are at the same level in the DOM like so

```
<body>
     <div class="modal-backdrop active">
     <div id="cordova-context-menu-wrapper">
</body>
```

Why is the popup not being clicked?

Snippet appears to work here but not in app, what could be possible reason for this?

```css
.modal-backdrop {
     position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="modal-backdrop active"><div class="modal-backdrop-bg"></div><div class="modal-wrapper" ng-transclude=""><ion-modal-view style="z-index:9;" class="modal slide-in-up ng-enter active ng-enter-active">
 <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="hideReplyModal()">Save</button>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title ng-binding title-left" style="left: 70px; right: 71px;">RE: Yyyhhy</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="sendReply()">Send</button>
    </div>

    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="scroll-content ionic-scroll overflow-scroll  has-header" autofocus=""><div class="scroll">

        <div style="padding:15px; height:100%;">
         <textarea placeholder="Type reply here..." style="font-size: 1.05em; line-height: 1.2em; height: 95%; width: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 99;" maxlength="50" ng-model="viewTicketsData.reply" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength"></textarea>
      <p id="charctersLeftP" class="ng-binding">32000</p>
     </div>
     

        

        
    </div></ion-content>

</ion-modal-view></div></div>
<div id="cordova-context-menu-wrapper"><style>#cordova-context-menu-wrapper{z-index:9999999999999;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:25px;width:100vw;height:100vh;margin:0 auto;padding:0;background:rgba(0,0,0,.55)}#cordova-context-menu{display:block;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;position:absolute;right:0;bottom:25px;left:0;width:100%;max-width:440px;height:auto;max-height:310px;margin:auto;background:#4b4b4b}#cordova-context-menu .cordova-context-menu-entry{display:block;height:60px;width:100%;padding:0 25px;font-size:16px;line-height:60px;color:#fff;cursor:pointer}#cordova-context-menu span{display:block;height:40px;width:100%;padding:0 10px;font-size:18px;line-height:40px;color:#fff;cursor:pointer}#cordova-context-menu .cordova-context-menu-entry:hover{background:rgba(255,255,255,.15)}</style><div id="cordova-context-menu"><span>Title</span><div class="cordova-context-menu-entry" data-id="test">Entry 1</div><div class="cordova-context-menu-entry" data-id="foo">Entry 2</div><div class="cordova-context-menu-entry" data-id="bar">Entry 3</div></div></div>
  </body>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: First off, it's good practice to keep z indices to the real levels. So, the modal gets the smallest z-index necessary to have it be above all the other content, and the popup gets that+1. Probably doesn't matter in this case, but I've run into cases where I had to use huge z-index values just because  a previous dev gave something else 99 when 3 would have done the trick

Comment: And the maximum z-index is 2147483647. Values higher than that will be treated as that. Shouldn't be a problem here, because 2147483647 > 10.

Comment: @henry I wouldn't say using the lowest possible z-index is a good idea. Sooner or later you need to put something between 2 and 3 and then you have to change all of your z-indexes.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Fair enough, multiples of 5 or 10 can be useful and like probably everyone I've used 99s, but I think real values are a good starting point and often suitable. Depends on the site/app of course